# Encrypt/Decrypt using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, file-upload, configuration, carrierwave

I want to make it so that my carrierwave uploader will encrypt files as it stores them and then decrypt them when they're being retrieved.

My first thought was to re-write the  CarrierWave::Uploader::Store::store! and  CarrierWave::Uploader::Store::retrieve_from_store! methods, to include my encryption and decryption code, but I'm not quite sure how to do this?

I'm planning on using Blowfish encryption.

Store

```
def store!(new_file=nil)
  # seems like I should process new_file here
  cache!(new_file) if new_file && ((@cache_id != parent_cache_id) || @cache_id.nil?)
  if @file and @cache_id
    with_callbacks(:store, new_file) do
      new_file = storage.store!(@file)
      @file.delete if (delete_tmp_file_after_storage && ! move_to_store)
      delete_cache_id
      @file = new_file
      @cache_id = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Retrieve from store

```
def retrieve_from_store!(identifier)
  with_callbacks(:retrieve_from_store, identifier) do
    res = storage.retrieve!(identifier)
    @file = res #process res before I store it to file?
  end
end
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? it's been years since you posted it but i'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this where the file is not actually being stored in the public directory. This would prevent a web crawler or someone guessing the file name and from downloading your file

```
  def store_dir
    "/path_to_rails_app/uploads/#{model.user_id}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

From here, you could use a `download` method and authorization tool to see if the user has access to download. Any ideas of the vunerabilities on this? Other than Mass Assignment or physical access to the machine, I don't think that it would be a big deal. You will also want to set the `cache_dir` to something outside of the public as well.

```
  def cache_dir
    "/path_to_rails_app/tmp/uploads/cache/#{model.user_id}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Comment: I like that idea, though I want to store my files using Fog on something like S3 or rackspace.

Comment: How about using the Carrierwave Encrypter Decrypter gem?

Comment: @Matthias That gem may work, but it doesn't appear to be maintained anymore as it has been almost two years without any commits.